# Qt QDateTime nanoseconds from 1/1/1970

Tags: qt, datetimeoffset, qdatetime

I am about to read data From a File which has stored it's time in nanoseconds from 1/1/1970. My problem is I want to read it to a `QDateTime` object, but it simply does not work as I want it to and the Qt Documentation did not help me either.

Note: milliseconds raster is enough for my purposes
Here my current approach:

```
void setDateTime(qint64 &ns)
{
    _datetime.setDate(QDate(1970,1,1));
    _datetime.setTime(QTime(0,0,0,0));
    ns /= 1000; //ns are now ms
    qDebug() << "| ms = " << ns;
    qDebug() << "| days = " << static_cast<int>(ns%(60*60*24*1E6));
    _datetime.addDays( static_cast<int>(ns%(60*60*24*1000)) );
    _datetime.addMSecs( ns - ((ns/(60*60*24*1000))*60*60*24*1E6) );
    qDebug() << "| dt = " << _datetime;
}
```

the result is always

```
 | dt =  QDateTime("Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970")
```

which is surely wrong

Can anybody tell where my flaw is? Thanks for any tips and help.

Edit: setTime_t is obviously what I wanted (except for msec resolution), and that works as expected, but I am really curious why the above approach does not work.

Edit changed hack-away bug from 1E6 multiplicative to 1E6

Comment: Note that 1000ns is 1us (microsecond), and QDateTime methods uses miliseconds. So you should probably divide ns by 1000000 instead od 1000.

Comment: You're right, but this was fixed in my code, just forgot to change in that "hackaway"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QDateTime::addDays()` and `QDateTime::addMSecs()` are const functions returning a new `QDateTime`. You're simply throwning the return value away.

And yes, this is written in the [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdatetime.html#addDays).

Comment: thank you very much
I was simply to tired yesterday... stupid fail :>